# Overflow clips tooltip

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tooltip, overflow

I'm using `flex` to position some divs around. When I try using a `tooltip` inside one of the divs that has `overflow-y: auto`, the tooltip text causes the div to overflow even while invisible, and is clipped when visible.

This is so when the tooltip text has `position: relative`.

If not, then it is not clipped, and it doesn't cause the div to overflow... but it is not positioned at the right place!

Any ideas how to make it be on the right place, and not be clipped? I have seen a couple of answers here that seem related, but didn't manage to fix my problem based on them.

Here's a very simple code that displays the problem

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 140px;
  height: 55px;
  /* the following style clips the tooltiptext (if it has position relative) */
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: aqua;
  /* to help see the overflow behaviour */
}

.container div {
  flex: 1;
}

.tooltip {
  width: 3em;
  height: 1em;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative; /* comment this out to fix clipping */
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  width: 6em;
  height: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  z-index: 1;
  /* The following is only good if position is relative */
  /* bottom: 125%; */
  /* left: 50%; */
  /* margin-left: -60px; */
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div>867-5309</div>
    <div class="tooltip">
      Busy
      <!-- If the position of the tooltiptext span is relative
          it causes the div to overflow - even when hidden,
          and the tooltiptext is clipped -->
      <span class="tooltiptext">When calling on Jan 2000</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is your desired output? What is the "right place"? `display: contents;` on tooltip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: contents;` on your tooltip.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 140px;
  height: 55px;
  /* the following style clips the tooltiptext (if it has position relative) */
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: aqua;
  /* to help see the overflow behaviour */
}

.container div {
  flex: 1;
}

.tooltip {
  display: contents;
  width: 3em;
  height: 1em;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  /* comment this out to fix clipping */
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  width: 6em;
  height: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  z-index: 1;
  /* The following is only good if position is relative */
  /* bottom: 125%; */
  /* left: 50%; */
  /* margin-left: -60px; */
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div>867-5309</div>
    <div class="tooltip">
      Busy
      <!-- If the position of the tooltiptext span is relative
          it causes the div to overflow - even when hidden,
          and the tooltiptext is clipped -->
      <span class="tooltiptext">When calling on Jan 2000<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71229271/overflow-clips-tooltip#/span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this solves the problem at least partly. Honestly I solved the problem by switching to jQuery tooltips.